# Using learned parameters to learn other parameters

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, neural-network

Is there a name for doing this--and if so, is it generally frowned upon? I'm unable to learn a certain model parameter with a net... but can get good results compared to ground-truth (lab tests) of other parameters. I am wondering if I can use those learned parameters as input to another net for learning the parameter that initially gave the algorithm a lot of difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

In general training one model to mimic the behavior of other models is called model transfer.  There is a rich and growing literature on it.  A lot of this work tends to be pretty researchy.  I particularly enjoyed the [Dark Knowledge](http://www.ttic.edu/dl/dark14.pdf) presentation by Geoffrey Hinton.

Comment: Terrific work by Hinton there. All of his work is worth reading. Lots of interesting, useful ideas.